# Change hardcoded value in executable

Tags: c#, .net, assembly, executable, game-engine

A new game released has been provided with server files that do not currently have the option of configuring an IP Address/Port for binding. Unfortunately this limits the ability to run more than one instance of the application per machine as it is hard-coded to port "12345".

Many years ago I was using c++ and hex editors to change hard coded values like this and while that knowledge has long since been forgotten, would it be possible to improve this by writing a secondary application to change that value at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still can use hex editor in order to change the hard coded constant.

Another way is to use debug api, provided by any decent OS. In Windows it is WriteProcessMemory function.

It looks following way - the launch application runs the modified application in debug mode. Changes needed constant and then runs it.

Of course, the modified application may use anti debugging techniques - in this case the solution is not trivial.

In both cases, you have to know where this value resides in the memory (executable file). This way some reverse engineering have to be provided.

Note, after the last question edits: All this answer is for native executable files. For managed code it probably is more complex.

Comment: I made some updates to my question but as your answer was applicable prior to me changing it around (probably should have made a new question post), I will go ahead and just accept this. Thank you!